# ElasticSearch: How to handle camel case and lowercase query

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, inverted-index

Let take the example of a title that we want to search. `somethingOtherThings`.
In this case we want to be able to query with:

- `something`
- `other`
- `things`

This is easily done with a [word delimiter token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html)

However there is some limit with that:

- query `otherthings` -> will NOT match
- query `otherThings` -> will match

So does there is an existing token filter that can split like [word delimiter token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) but also group those word:

- something
- other
- things
- somethingotherthings
- somethingother
- otherthings

So if we have that, we have indexed all the possible options.

Comment: Elasticsearch needs some signal to know where to spilt tokens. In the case of the word delimiter token filter and a camel cased word, it can use the signal of case change to split. With a compound word of two words, with no clear signal to identify a word boundary, how would a token filter know where to split? For a subset of known words, a dictionary and some heuristics may work, but for a generalized pattern this is going to be much trickier, possibly not feasible.

Comment: What I want is something that split camel case. (like word delimiter) but also create some subset: 
For example: 

 - still split on all the uppercase.
 - and then make all the possibility by grouping those words.

so If we split `AaBbCcDdEe` I want to have `Aa` `Bb` `Cc` `Dd` `Ee` seachable but also all the pattern like `AaBb` `AaBbCc` `AaBbCcDd` `AaBbCcDdEe` and `BbCc` etc

As you can see we know how to split: uppercase, but just want to combine the result of the split

Comment: You can achieve this with a word delimiter token filter followed by a shingle token filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html

Comment: Oh thx this is excatly what I dreamt of ;)